# Can JsonPath be used to validate multiple paths?

Tags: java, jsonpath

I need to verify that JSON contains values in two fields.

Can I verify that some JSON contains two values, for example ...

```
$.field1.field2 = test && $.field3[*].field4 = test2
```

...using [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)?

I can successfully validate one field but I don't know how to validate multiple fields

Comment: Please attach the non-working code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JsonPath `Filter` for each condition and you can combine filters with `and`.

For example:

```
Filter combinedFilter = Filter.filter(
     Criteria.where("$.field1.field2").is("test").and("$.field3[*].field4").is("test2")
);

JsonPath.parse(json).read("$", combinedFilter);
```

More details [in the docs](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-predicates).